# "Deadlock" with MPI_Waitall

Tags: c++, mpi, deadlock

I am trying to send some data from each process to both its neighbors (by rank). To do this I am trying to use the non-blocking send and receive calls `MPI_Isend`/`MPI_Irecv` and a corresponding call to `MPI_Waitall` to make sure the transfer has happened before using the data.

Below is a minimal example of what I'm trying to do

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int rank,comm_size;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&comm_size);

    MPI_Request reqs[4];

    int sbuff1[10];
    int sbuff2[10];
    int rbuff1[10];
    int rbuff2[10];

    int count = 0;

    if(rank>0)
    {
        MPI_Irecv(rbuff1,10,MPI_INT,rank-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;
        MPI_Isend(sbuff1,10,MPI_INT,rank-1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;
    }

    if(rank<comm_size-1)
    {
        MPI_Irecv(rbuff2,10,MPI_INT,rank+1,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;
        MPI_Isend(sbuff2,10,MPI_INT,rank+1,3,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;
    }

    MPI_Waitall(count,reqs,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    if(rank==0)
            cout << "Successfully exchanged data." << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this code never makes it through to print out the message at the end.

My question is then: are the data being sent correctly but my call to `MPI_Waitall` is somehow wrong? If so what do I need to change to make this simple code run and if not what else is awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags for send/recv you set are never matching.

This little fix

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int rank,comm_size;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&comm_size);

    MPI_Request reqs[4];

    int sbuff1[10];
    int sbuff2[10];
    int rbuff1[10];
    int rbuff2[10];

    int count = 0;

    if(rank>0)
    {

        MPI_Irecv(rbuff1,10,MPI_INT,rank-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;
        MPI_Isend(sbuff1,10,MPI_INT,rank-1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;
    }

    if(rank<comm_size-1)
    {
        /// changed tag 2 -> 1 
        // MPI_Irecv(rbuff2,10,MPI_INT,rank+1,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        MPI_Irecv(rbuff2,10,MPI_INT,rank+1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;

        /// changed tag 3 -> 0 
        // MPI_Isend(sbuff2,10,MPI_INT,rank+1,3,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        MPI_Isend(sbuff2,10,MPI_INT,rank+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqs[count]);
        count++;
    }

    MPI_Waitall(count,reqs,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    if(rank==0)
            cout << "Successfully exchanged data." << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

makes it work

```
$> mpirun -n 5 ./testling 
Successfully exchanged data.
```

Ran on x86_84 Linux with mpich2 v1.5 (Hydra)

Comment: Doh! I did try different tags but I guess I didn't hit on the right combination. I never really understood what the tags were used for. I've written programs before which arbitrarily incremented tags after each MPI call and this worked fine?

Comment: If the dialog is synchronous and both increment the tag properly, there no harm to be expected. Btw - I did not want to patch too intrusively but I think  you'd do better with sort of ((rank + 1) % comm_size) branch logic.

Comment: I don't need to transfer between the first and last processes so as it stands is okay, but thanks.